# use of undeclared identifyer

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to objective c and I am programming in Xcode, I am making a windowed application just to learn and test what i have learned, but i have run into a problem that i cannot seem to find the answer to.

```
NSString *textArea = [textAreaVisual Hello World];
```

I am trying to send a text area, or label, a value to put onto the screen, but i always get the error:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'textAreaVisual'

*note i am new to objective c and cocoa, i do know some c++
**note i am also new to Stackoverflow, so if i did something wrong here I'm sorry

Comment: what is textAreaVisual? post some more of your code

Comment: Not only is `textAreaVisual` not defined, but `Hello World` would clearly be an unrecognized selector...

Comment: textAreaVisual is something i made up to distinguish between textArea and textAreaVisual seeing that i thought that the textAreaVisual is the part that was going to be put on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like, you could simply display a value on the screen through an action, such as a button pressed on the screen. You could first create an `IBOutlet` for your label, name it `textArea`. To create the IBOutlet, simply right-click and drag from your `UIlabel` object to your header(.h)file. Then you could drag an `UIButton` object from your object library onto your `UIViewController`.

Once this is done, simply right-click and drag from the button to your ViewController's header(.h) file, create an `IBAction`, call it say "changeText", and then Xcode will create that `IBAction` automatically in your implementation(.m) file, where you can then just place `textArea.text = @"Place text here";` inside your IBAction like this:

```
- (IBAction)changeText:(UIButton *)sender
{
     textArea.text = @"Place text here";
}
```

You could even just create a `UITapGestureRecognizer` that will fire a method to place text in your `UILabel` like this:

in your `viewDidLoad:` method:

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeText)];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

then in your class place this method:

```
- (void)changeText
{
    textArea.text = @"Place text here";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've properly created an `NSTextField` (we'll call it `textField`) and made it uneditable (which is how you'd make a label), you can set the text in it like this:

```
[textField setStringValue:@"Hello World"];
```

From a syntax perspective, this is roughly equivalent to the following C++ snippet:

```
textField.setStringValue("Hello World");
```

Comment: i did what you said to do but it says to replace
 
[textField setStringValue:@"Hello World"]; 

with 

"[NSTextField setStringValue:@"Hello World"]; 

and even after that it has an error at set string value, i put a standard label down in the MainMenu.xib but i don't know how to link it or if i need to put something in the place holder